# how find $f(f(f(2^{1388})))$ ? when `f(x)` is sum of digits of `x`

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

We define `f(n) = sum of digits of n`.

Is there a simple and logical way for calculate $f(f(f(2^{1388})))$?

thanks in advance.

Comment: It's only a 418 digit number which can be easily computed by a computer, and the digital root is 1930. Repeating twice gives 4.

Comment: @T.Bongers I want to solve it without computer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sum of digits is essentially a logarithm, so it is much smaller than the number.  The value $\bmod 9$ stays the same when you take the sum of digits.  As a practical matter, these questions always have enough sums of digits to get down to a single digit number, so you want $2^{1388} \bmod 9$.  You really should justify that you get down to a single digit, which you can do by saying $2^{1388}$ has $418$ digits, so the sum of digits is at most $9\cdot 418$, which has a sum of digits at most ___, etc.

Comment: why mod 9 stays the same?

Comment: It is the classic [divisibility test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule) for $9$.  It works because $10^n \equiv 1 \bmod 9$  You can then see that the powers of $2$ go through a cycle $\bmod 9$ to find $2^{1388} \bmod 9$ by hand