# Show that $Q(Q(Q(2005^{2005})))=7$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, modular-arithmetic

Recently, I have found this problem:

> Let $Q(n)$ denote the sum of the digits of a positive integer $n$. Prove that:  $$Q(Q(Q(2005^{2005})))=7$$

This topic is related to other two question I have asked: [Sum of number's digits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3282822/sum-of-numbers-digits) and [Simplifying an expression with modulus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3284384/simplifying-an-expression-with-modulus).

I have tried to solve this problem in many different ways, for example using the formula: $$Q(n)= n - 9 \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\log_{10} n\rfloor}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{10^k}\right\rfloor$$ but I'm stuck when I have to compute: $$Q(2005^{2005} - 9 \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\log_{10} 2005^{2005}\rfloor}\left\lfloor\frac{2005^{2005}}{10^k}\right\rfloor)= 2005^{2005} - 9 \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\log_{10} 2005^{2005}\rfloor}\left\lfloor\frac{2005^{2005}}{10^k}\right\rfloor- 9 \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\log_{10} \left ( 2005^{2005} - 9 \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\log_{10} 2005^{2005}\rfloor}\left\lfloor\frac{2005^{2005}}{10^k}\right\rfloor \right )\rfloor}\left\lfloor\frac{2005^{2005} - 9 \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\log_{10} 2005^{2005}\rfloor}\left\lfloor\frac{2005^{2005}}{10^k}\right\rfloor}{10^k}\right\rfloor$$

Or in other words, letting: $\Upsilon =2005^{2005} - 9 \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\log_{10} 2005^{2005}\rfloor}\left\lfloor\frac{2005^{2005}}{10^k}\right\rfloor $: $$Q(\Upsilon)=\Upsilon-9 \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\log_{10} \Upsilon\rfloor}\left\lfloor\frac{\Upsilon}{10^k}\right\rfloor$$

I have tried also using infinite sum, like complex Fourier series (see also this post [Expression for finding sum of number's digits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3297089/expression-for-finding-sum-of-numbers-digits)), but I don't know how to pass from an infinite series to the effective result.

Comment: Some similar questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/169797/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2966184/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1906448/42969

Comment: I strongly assume that the same technique (computing $2005^{2005} \bmod 9$) works here as well (and the question can be closed as a duplicate).

Comment: Can you explain how $\mod 9$ can be used?

Comment: Did you have a look at the answers to those 3 similar questions?

Comment: Hint :$\lceil \log (2005^{2005}) \rceil = \lceil 2005\log (2005) \rceil = 6621$, so $Q(2005^{2005}) \lt 9 \times 6621 = 59589$ etc.