# Digit sum of digit sum of $2020^{2021}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $S(n)$ be the sum of the digits of a non-negative integer $n$. What is $S\left(S\left(2020^{2021}\right)\right)$?

Other than seeing that this is $7 \pmod 9$ (since every non-negative integer is congruent to its digit sum $\mod 9$), I'm not sure what else can be done.

Comment: Well, it's easy to come close.  Taking logs, we can get the number of digits in $2020^{2021}$, so taking crude estimates gets the answer down to a very short list.

Comment: The last $2021$ digits are zero.

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1906448/42969 for a similar question and the general idea.

Comment: The answer appears to be 16.
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+digits+of+2020%5E2021

Comment: LOL, @player3236

Comment: @Above. I agree that using logs we can deduce that the answer is either $7$, $16$, $25$, or $34$. But how can we go beyond that? And obviously, I am interested in how to find this without a calculator/computer.

Comment: **Heuristically,** the typical nonzero digit is $5$, giving an estimate of $5(6681-2021)\approx 23000$ for the first sum. By the same typical-digit-argument, we expect the second sum to roughly equal the digit sum of 15555, or 21. This makes 7 and 34 heuristically inplausible, but the way I wrote it is awfully undecided about 16 vs 25

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Isn't the average digit 4.5, not 5?

Comment: It's 16, but I doubt that you can solve this without computer

Comment: @Oldboy This problem comes from a competition where no calculators/computers could be used. So I think there must be some way to solve it without those.

Comment: What's the competition?

Comment: @Dr. Mathva Singapore Mathematical Olympiad: http://www.realsutra.com/limjeck/SMO_Senior_2020.pdf, Problem 24.

Comment: Read the problem statement carefully: you should evaluate $S\left(S\left(S\left(2020^{2021}\right)\right)\right)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When reading carefully the problem in the pdf you linked, one realizes that it asks for $S\left(S\left(S\left(2020^{2021}\right)\right)\right)$ rather than for $S\left(S\left(2020^{2021}\right)\right)$. I do not think that there is a reasonable method to evaluate the latter without a computer; notwithstanding, the actual answer is doable.

Observe, first of all, that $2020^{2021}$ has $\lceil 2021\cdot \log_{10}(2020)\rceil=6681$ digits; the last $2021$ are, of course, zeroes, since $10\mid 2020$. Thus $$S\left(2020^{2021}\right)\leqslant (6681-2021)\cdot 9=41940$$ We similarly obtain $$S\left(S\left(2020^{2021}\right)\right)\leqslant 4+4\cdot 9=40$$ At the same time, since $S(x)\equiv x\bmod 9$, we have $$S\left(S\left(2020^{2021}\right)\right)\equiv 2020^{2021}\equiv 4^{2021}\equiv 4^{336\cdot 6+5}\equiv 4^5\equiv 7\mod 9$$ Where I used [that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) $\varphi(9)=6$. Hence $$S\left(S\left(2020^{2021}\right)\right)\in\{7, 16, 25, 34\}$$ Therefore, $S\left(S\left(S\left(2020^{2021}\right)\right)\right)=7.$